# Multiple enemies with their own audio sources and clips makes my game's audio lag

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game that will have tons of enemies in one scene and each of them has their own Audio Source and Clips.

My issue is, when they all start to stack around me and shoots me, the audio lags so much. The background music is cutting off, my shooting sfx is cutting off, explosion sfx is cutting off, etc...

Basically what's going on is that there's like 50+ audios playing at the same time and the sound breaks :/.

I'm using the PlayOneShot function on everything, btw.

What's the best way to handle game audio in terms of having multiple audio sources and clips at the same time?

Comment: Is it a 2D game or a 3D game? Does every enemy need its own Audio Source? Couldn't it be solved by having one Audio Source (e.g. on camera object) and playing everything through that?
Also, what quality of the audio files do you use? What options do you see when you click on the audio asset? A screenshot could help too.

Comment: - It's a 2D game using 3D audio sources.
- Somewhat yes. I want this 3D sound effect when the audio source is far away from the camera, the volume changes.
- I wouldn't want to do that because it would be weird hearing a loud sfx of an enemy shooting for afar.
- I use a WAV format if that's what you're asking.
- Idk what you mean by that.

Comment: I wish I could help you more, but it's really hard to tell. Personally, I would try playing with the options for the assets - for example, click on the asset (the audio file) directly in Unity editor and change `Load Type` to `Decompress On Load` and `Compression Format` to `ADPCM` or `Vorbis`. Also try changing `Sample Rate Setting`. More [about these options here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioClip.html). Having many sounds at once, you might not need a high WAV level of sound quality. Also, does this happen only in editor, or in build too? What platform are you building for?

Comment: 50+ audios? what type of game is that? Is it looping sound? You need to optimize your audio or your game. I think its not good if you hear 50+ sfx at the same time. make you the objects is destroyed and not just hidden on the screen if it dies or something like that.

Comment: @Arx, thanks for the tips and I'll be sure to try them out! This happens on the editor and it's for Android. Although, I kinda fixed the issue of the background music cutting. I just had to put bgm priority to 0, player shooting sfx to 1, enemy explosion sfx to 2, and enemy shooting sfx to 3 and it all sounds smooth now. But I'm still worried about the fact that it might be a bad practice to have multiple enemies having their own audio sources.

Comment: @Kris, basically, when the game starts to become harder, at least 50+ enemies will start hoarding around you and those 50+ enemies will be shooting all at the same time with the same sfx. I'm trying to figure out a good way to code audios with multiple enemies while being able to keep the "3D effect" on each enemies... And yeah, the objects do get destroyed after they die.

Comment: @PenguinsFly you can also try having only one `AudioSource` and using [PlayClipAtPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html) - maybe this would achieve the same 3D effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically you won't need everyone of them to have an audioclip, especially if they're the same kind; and double especially if there's a huge mass of them. Maybe use SetActive(true/false) to turn some on and if there's (x) amount surrounding the player, SetActive to false for a majority of them.